# Pass a parameter to a menu walker

Tags: menus, walker

Is there any way to pass a parameter to a menu walker? I'm trying to write a BEM-style walker, and I'd like to be able to pass a class to apply to the menu links via the walker. Something like:

```
<?php
wp_nav_menu(array(
    "container"      => false,
    "depth"          => 3,
    "items_wrap"     => "%3\$s",
    "theme_location" => "primary",
    "walker"         => new BEMwalker("mobile"),
));
?>
```

Comment: Can you access the menu args from the walker? Just had a quick read through the docs and it _might_ be possible...? If so, you could add a custom argument

Comment: Alternatively you can use a filter to modify the menu links directly, it's `wp_nav_menu_items` or similar. The `$args` are then definitely available in there.

Comment: You are doing it right already. Just change the constructor to keep that value in a private member.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @toscho said, you can call the walker class with parameters as you did:

```
new BEMwalker( 'mobile' )
```

The constructor of `BEMwalker` will take the arguments (like any other function or method in PHP) so you can access the parameter(s) via `$this`:

```
class BEMwalker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

    private $classes;

    public function __construct( $classes = '' ) {
        $this->classes = $classes;
    }

    public function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
       $output .= sprintf( "<li class=\"%s\"><a href=\"%s\">%s</a></li>",
            $this->classes,
            $item->url,
            $item->title
        );
    }

}
```

Further reading: There's also a GitHub repository called [WordPress BEM Menu](https://github.com/roikles/Wordpress-Bem-Menu) which might help you to implement a BEM-like syntax.

Comment: Thanks much! I'm not the best with PHP, but I figured the answer would be this simple :) I'll give this a shot on Monday.